# Is it possible for ntheorem to number each instance with subscript numbers?

Tags: numbering, subscripts, ntheorem

I am wondering if it is possible to alter ntheorem's numbering of theorems/hypotheses/instances with subscript numbers. I could not find anything on this matter in the package's documentation, which has options for arabic, greek, alph, roman and so on, but not regarding subcript numbers.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem, fixltx2e, hyperref}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\begin{document}
Below is my first hypothesis.
\begin{hyp}[H\ref{hyp:h1}] \label{hyp:h1}
The apple seldom falls far from the tree.
\end{hyp}
Below is my second hypothesis.
\begin{hyp}[H\ref{hyp:h2}] \label{hyp:h2}
All swans are white.
\end{hyp}
I am interested in the "H label" appearing like so: \textbf{Hypothesis 2 (H\textsubscript{2})}.
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the output of the code above]
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2)Since this is the "extra" argument, the formatting is provided by you and not my ntheorem` or any of the other theorem packages. So you basically have to add it by hand, wrap the `\ref{...}` with `\textsubscript{...}`

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to want the same number, you don't really need `\label` and `\ref`. It's easier defining a new environment based on a theorem-like one. I also provided a new `\hypref` command for referencing to hypotheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem,hyperref}

\theoremseparator{:}

\newtheorem{hypx}{Hypothesis}
\newenvironment{hyp}{\hypx[H\textsubscript{\thehypx}]}{\endhypx}
\newcommand{\hypref}[1]{\textup{(H\textsubscript{\ref{#1}})}}

\begin{document}

Below is my first hypothesis.

\begin{hyp}\label{hyp:h1}
The apple seldom falls far from the tree.
\end{hyp}

Below is my second hypothesis.

\begin{hyp}
All swans are white.
\end{hyp}

Here is a reference to \hypref{hyp:h1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow cheers - that works absolutely perfectly! Thanks a lot!