# Theorem numbering as subscript

Tags: ntheorem

The following thread gives "Hypothesis 1 (H_1)" as output. Is it possible to just have "H_1" instead? The subscript is needed.

[Is it possible for ntheorem to number each instance with subscript numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318901/is-it-possible-for-ntheorem-to-number-each-instance-with-subscript-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I modified https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388602/17360.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\newtheoremstyle{hypstyle}% name
{3pt}% Space above1
{3pt}% Space below1
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount2
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head3
{\thmname{#1}$_{\thmnumber{#2}}$}% THEOREM HEAD SPEC (IF EMPTY MEANS `NORMAL')
\theoremstyle{hypstyle}
\newtheorem{hyp}{H}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
test    
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
second
\end{hyp}



\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image: preview]

Or are you bound to `ntheorem`?